# Better way to check Parameters?

Tags: javascript, java, c#

In various situations I'm confronted with the problem, that I need to check the parameters of a function to guarantee a correct program flow.

I found that it is becoming to be a bit tedious to create if-else blocks just to check for nullpointer, ranges of numbers, correct strings, correct objects and so on. Besides the code becomes more difficult to read and thus it becomes more difficult to have the overview.

So I thought what if there is a way in java/javascript/c#... (programming languages with functions in it) where you can define some pre-conditions.

So for e.g. in java:

```
  void doSomething( int a {0 <= a < 10}, String b {b != "wrong" && b != [1-9]}){
   ...
  }
```

or something like this:

```
  §a: 0 <= a && 10 > a || a == 25 ...
  §b: ...
  §ifWrongPreConditions: return; //or throw a new default Exception or whatever
  void doSomething( int a, String b){
    §a: 0 <= a && 10 > a || a == 25 ...
    §b: ...
    §ifWrongPreConditions: return; //or throw a new default Exception or whatever
  ...Code...
  }
```

or above the method head. 
Basically the second idea could help for post-conditions too and you only need one look at the function to know what you need to do so that the function is working correct.

But I'm not sure if there is something like already implemented, 
but I want to have it a little easier to become an overview over the "meta-info" of a function so can anticipate the desired and undesired behavior and it might be easier to make it work with OCL.

So back to the question: Is there a good way to define Pre-, Post-Conditions, maybe Invariants for methods (maybe classes and similar stuff) that are easy to read in the respective language?

(P.S. Im not sure if the tags I set here are "correct", because it is a practical question for different languages about a concept that might confront programmers in those languages. Sorry in advance for that)

Comment: You might want to look at [Microsoft Code Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts) and the [tag:code-contracts] tag. Betrand Meyer introduced [Design by Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) in the Eiffel programming language.

Comment: Sorry, but you should ask **one** question per question. Tagging with 3 really different languages is the exact opposite of that. Please make up your mind and **only** ask for one specific language. Exactly because the answers heavily depend on the target language.

Comment: @Josh - Removing those tags clearly conflicts with the author's intent, I've rolled back the edit. The intent may be incorrect, and I'm a bit surprised not to find a "language-neutral" tag (I hesitate to create one, not least because I think there used to be one and so it may have been burninated), but we can't narrow the focus to just one language on their behalf. (We could remove all three language tags if we can find something else appropriate to tag with...)

Comment: @GhostCat Well I know I was a bit lazy to ask the same question just with a different tag. Since I have to work with various Languages I wanted an overview of possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

Java has no argument validation feature in the JDK. 
However, there is [specification for Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) which has similar capabilities.  and there are 3rd party libraries and frameworks that implement above mentioned specification. One of the popular frameworks is Spring which has a module for annotation based [Validation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)

Here is an example for such validation:

```
package hello;

import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class PersonForm {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Min(18)
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person(Name: " + this.name + ", Age: " + this.age + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, with Spring you can use javax.validation constraints on method parameters and return values, provided that said method are in a class annotated with @org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated

Answer (score 1):

Answering for Java first. There we have [bean validation](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/):

- you use a declarative approach, by using **annotations** on the "data structures" that your code will be using
- you then have *some* framework "in the background" that takes care of **validating** actual data against the declared expectations

The essential thought here: you absolutely do **not** validate data structures "manually". Instead, you establish a notation that can be applied to such structures, and then you have a generic framework to turn declarations into runtime checks.

JavaScript has similar ideas, see the [validatejs](https://validatejs.org/) library for example.

And of course, same things exist in C#, too. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159234/validation-framework-in-c) SO question for example.

Answer (score 1):

[*Assertions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)) are a fairly standard cross-language approach. The nice thing about assertions is that, in most environments, you can include them for testing, but turn them off for release builds on the theory you've found the bugs they defend against. For that reason, assertions are *not* the way to handle user input, of course.

Java has direct support for them ([`assert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10)), as does the .Net platform ([`Debug.Assert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert(v=vs.110).aspx)). JavaScript doesn't have direct support for assertions, but they're readily added with a utility function, or you could write a Babel plug-in for them that compiles the assertion to nothing for release builds.

`assert` example:

```
void doSomething(int a, String b) {
    assert a >= 0 && a < 10;
    assert !b.equals("wrong") && /*...your second condition didn't make sense for strings */;
}
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. The only thing that bothers me though, is that you still need to code the same way as before, because there is the possibility to switch-off the assertions. So its more to test the code rather than garantee a correct flow. But this is and will be very useful to me. Thank you.

Comment: @telion - The idea is that you don't need those checks at runtime because you've already tested thoroughly and know that the values will be in-range. All you need to do is validate user input, at the point of receipt, not every parameter of every method (because your testing tells you you haven't got those wrong). :-)